# Which are the most important features I will miss targeting Android API 3 (OS 1.5) instead of most recent API?

Tags: java, android, backwards-compatibility

I'm beginning with Android development. I'm aware that there is a lot of Android devices still on OS 1.5 or 1.6 so I'm thinking about require API level 3 as minimum to support them.

What will I miss from 2.2?

Comment: That really depends on what your app is focused on.  Can you tell us more about it?

Comment: There's a LOT of changes from 1.5 to 2.2. It's barely the same OS. Think windows 95 to windows 7

Answer (score 1):

You can make your app backward compatible. You will have to specify the target SDK as 2.2 and the min SDK as 1.5

There are a few strategies to use when you are making a backward compatible application. The thing you need to avoid is using functionality from a higher SDK (APIs etc) when your application is running on a phone that supports a lower SDK. Read http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html for more information.

Another good read on how lazy loading of classes can be used for backward compatibility - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html

Answer (score 1):

The thing I miss the most when I target Android 1.5 is a usable [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).  1.5's implementation of RelativeLayout is famously buggy and often requires you to use all sorts of awkward workarounds and extra view nesting that can be avoided on Android 1.6+.  For instance, the [layout_center*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_centerInParent) properties rarely work properly on 1.5, and they're one of the most useful features of RelativeLayout.

Comment: will evaluate that issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add to this list lack of "onClick" attribute in 1.5 layouts schema